# could be appealing/attractive to him

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

May I know is **could be appealing/attractive to him** in the below sentence grammatical and idiomatic?

> I guess an opportunity to come to Singapore **could be
>   appealing/attractive to him**, as I remember he told me that Singapore
>   is a great country previously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are both fine. They are interchangeable in this context and you people will use and understand both. I'd say attractive is probably a bit more common.